# Время выполнения кода

Tags: время, c++, visual-c++

Какую функцию стоит использовать, чтобы получить значение, которое не будет фиксировать время других процессов?
Язык С++

Comment: @Ацамаз Датиев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Язык C++ не знает о существовании операционной системы и других процессах, поэтому он такого сервиса не предоставляет.

Таким образом, вам нужно воспользоваться системно-зависимыми функциями, под каждой системой своими (а под некоторыми таких функций может и не оказаться). Например, под Windows это [`GetThreadTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

В  зависимости от ситуации пользуюсь `clock()`, `clock_gettime()`, `gettimeofday()` или `setitimer()/getitimer()/timer_settime()/timer_gettime()`. Но это в Linux и скорее относится к Си.

Судя по метке vc++ у Вас Windows.

Хотя `clock()`, безусловно там должна быть, но вот ее поведение относительно времени других процессов, мне неизвестно.

Попробуйте посмотреть [C++ Time library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)